# Add scroll in the responsive menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to customize responsive menu "Bootstrap" and I stuck on one final point.

I would like the content menu with the id "menuNavBar" is scrollable, but I can surely not because of positions "absolute"?

```
#slide-nav #slidemenu
    {
        background: #f7f7f7;
        right: -100%;
        width: 300px;
        min-width: 0;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 0 10px;
        z-index: 2;
        top: -8px;
        margin: 0;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 12px #555;
        border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
    }

    #slide-nav.navbar
    {
        height: auto;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #C0B0AA;
    }

#slide-nav #menuNavBar
    {
        padding-top: 80px;
    }
```

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/corgato/pen/BzgXKm)

Comment: Makes no difference; you can just use `overflow:scroll` to add scrollbars, or `overflow:auto` to automatically add scrollbars if necessary. Remember that the contents would have to be bigger than the scrollable element for anything to actually happen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `height` and add `overflow:hidden` to add scroll.

Update your CSS with the following:

```
#slide-nav #slidemenu {
  background: #f7f7f7 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 12px #555;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -100%;
  top: -8px;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 2;
  /* add the following CSS */
  overflow: auto; 
  height: 300px;
 }
```

**UPDATE:**

Adding height to the div using jQuery

```
function setHeight() {
    windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
    $('.divClassName').css('height', windowHeight);
};
setHeight();
$(window).resize(function() {
    setHeight();
});
```

**Updated [Codepen](http://codepen.io/sanjeevks121/pen/RRXvWx) here**

Comment: Why "height:100%" does not ?

Comment: you will have to specify fixed value of height, 100% would not work, you can apply the height to div using JS, first get the height of viewport and then apply that height to div.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant "height: auto" because I want the div is scrollable only if the phone screen / tablet is too small, but the menu are good size it needs automatically.

Comment: Yes, height:auto will not work since the div is in absolute position, try adding height using JS, so every screen size will have different fixed height and scroll will be added when required since its overflow:auto

Comment: How can I manage all screen sizes? This is not how heavy system?

Comment: I have updated my answer above with jQuery which will add height to div according to viewport height based on the screen size. just replace the class "divClassName" with your class

Comment: The code does not work.
For example if I set a height of 300px, and the smartphone screen is smaller vera is not the rest of the same menu with the scroll.
We must find a way to manage the height in auto

Comment: You missed my last comment, I have added height using jQuery, this way the height would be added as per the screen size, not a predefined height. check above the updated answer.

Comment: Check this updated codepen, I have created for you: http://codepen.io/sanjeevks121/pen/RRXvWx

Comment: you mean, its missing bottom curves?

Comment: No, the link "Aide" is not visible

Comment: not clear what you mean, are you checking the codepen I have updated? http://codepen.io/sanjeevks121/pen/RRXvWx if you cant see the text, you can scroll and see..

Comment: If I reduce the high window and I open the menu I do not see all the same menu by scrolling through the menu, I miss several links such "aide" is not visible. (with your code on codepen.io)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    // Scroll minim header
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(document).scrollTop() > 50)
            $('#slide-nav').addClass('shrink');
        else
            $('#slide-nav').removeClass('shrink');
    });


    // Open modal connexion
    $('.btn-register').on('click', function() {
        whichtab = $(this).data('opentab');
        $('#ModalConnexionLabel').modal('show');
        $('.nav-tabs li:eq('+whichtab+') a').tab('show');
    });


    // annimation burger bootstrap
    $(".navbar-toggle").on("click", function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });


    // Menu responsive
    //stick in the fixed 100% height behind the navbar but don't wrap it
    $('#slide-nav.navbar-inverse').after($('<div class="inverse" id="navbar-height-col"></div>'));
    $('#slide-nav.navbar-default').after($('<div id="navbar-height-col"></div>'));

    // Enter your ids or classes
    var toggler = '.navbar-toggle';
    var pagewrapper = '#page';
    var navigationwrapper = '.navbar-header';
    var menuwidth = '100%'; // the menu inside the slide menu itself
    var slidewidth = '0%';
    var menuneg = '-100%';
    var slideneg = '-80%';

    $("#slide-nav").on("click", toggler, function(e)
    {
        var selected = $(this).hasClass('slide-active');

        $('#slidemenu').stop().animate({
            right: selected ? menuneg : '0px'
        });

        $('#navbar-height-col').stop().animate({
            right: selected ? slideneg : '0px'
        });

        $(pagewrapper).stop().animate({
            right: selected ? '0px' : slidewidth
        });

        $(navigationwrapper).stop().animate({
            right: selected ? '0px' : slidewidth
        });

        $(this).toggleClass('slide-active', !selected);
        $('#slidemenu').toggleClass('slide-active');

        $(pagewrapper+', .navbar, body, '+navigationwrapper).toggleClass('slide-active');
    });

    var selected = '#slidemenu, '+pagewrapper+', body, .navbar, '+navigationwrapper;

    $(window).on("resize", function()
    {
        if($(window).width() > 1032 && $(toggler).is(':hidden'))
        {
            $(selected).removeClass('slide-active');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
/* put toggle bars on the left :: not using button */
#slide-nav .navbar-toggle {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 0;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    border: 0;
    background: transparent;
    z-index: 999;
}

/* icon bar prettyup - optional */
#slide-nav .navbar-header {
    position: relative
}
/* un fix the navbar when active so that all the menu items are accessible */
.navbar.navbar-fixed-top.slide-active {
    position: relative
}

#slide-nav.navbar
{
    background-color: #FFF;
}




/* START scroll resize */
nav.navbar.shrink
{
    min-height: 35px;
}

nav.shrink .navbar-brand
{
    font-size: 25px;
}

nav.shrink .navbar-toggle
{
    padding: 4px 5px;
    margin: 8px 15px 8px 0;
}

nav.shrink .navbar-brand img
{
    height: 46px;
}

#slide-nav .navbar-brand {
    height: auto;
}
/* END scroll Resize */




/* screw writing importants and shit, just stick it in max width since these classes are not shared between sizes */
@media (max-width:1032px)
{
    /*wrap the entire page content but not nav inside this div if not a fixed top, don't add any top padding */
    #page {
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 80px;
        left: 0;
    }

    #slide-nav
    {
        position: fixed;
        border-top: 0;
    }

    #slide-nav #menu-aide
    {
        visibility: hidden;
        display: none !important;
    }

    #slide-nav #menu-global .dropdown-toggle
    {
        visibility: hidden;
        display: none !important;
    }

    #slide-nav .navbar-brand img
    {
        height: 46px;
    }

    #slide-nav #slidemenu .avatar-navbar-xs
    {
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
    }

    #slide-nav .container {
        margin: 0!important;
        padding: 0!important;
        height:100%;
    }

    #slide-nav .navbar-header
    {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0 15px;
    }

    #slide-nav .navbar.slide-active
    {
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        top: -1px;
        z-index: 1000;
    }

    #slide-nav #slidemenu {
  background: #f7f7f7 none repeat scroll 1 1;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 12px #555;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -100%;
  top: -8px;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: auto; 
  height: 300px;
 }

    #slide-nav.navbar
    {
        height: auto;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #C0B0AA;
    }

    #slide-nav #menuNavBar
    {
        padding-top: 80px;
    }

    #slide-nav #slidemenu .navbar-nav
    {
        min-width: 0;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #slide-nav #slidemenu .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu li a
    {
        min-width: 0;
        width: 100%;
        white-space: normal;
    }

    #slide-nav.navbar-inverse #slidemenu
    {
        background: #333;
    }

    /* this is behind the navigation but the navigation is not inside it so that the navigation is accessible and scrolls */
    #slide-nav #navbar-height-col
    {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        height: 100%;
        bottom:0;
        width: 80%;
        right: -80%;
        background: #f7f7f7;
    }

    #slide-nav #navbar-height-col.inverse
    {
        background: #333;
        z-index: 1;
        border: 0;
    }

    #slide-nav .btn
    {
        margin: 0 15%;
        width: 70%;
    }

    #slide-nav .navbar-toggle .icon-bar
    {
        background-color: #E8412A;
        z-index: 999;
    }

    #slide-nav .picto-margin-right
    {
        width: 45px;
        line-height: 40px;
    }

    #slide-nav .btn-middle
    {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    #slide-nav .avatar-navbar-xs
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        left: 15px;
    }

    #slide-nav .navbar-cart
    {
        position: absolute;
        top:20px;
        right: 60px;
    }

    #slide-nav .navbar-cart i
    {
        color: #E8412A;
    }

    #slide-nav .nabvar-cart-nb
    {
        position: absolute;
        top:-8px;
        right: 15px;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background-color: #23527c;
        border-radius: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #FFF;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    #slide-nav .navbar-nav > li > a.navbar-btn {
        padding-top: 4px;
        padding-bottom: 4px;
        width: 70%;
    }


    #slide-nav .bloc-no-visibility-sm
    {
        visibility: hidden;
        display: none !important;
    }


    /* Show menu when open navbar */
    #slide-nav #menu-global .dropdown-menu
    {
        border:0;
        border-top: 1px solid #EEE;
        display: block;
        position: static;
        float: none;
        width: auto;
        margin-top: 20px;
        background-color: transparent;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }


    /* Effect icon burger */
    #slide-nav .navbar-toggle .icon-bar:nth-of-type(2) {
        top: 1px;
    }

    #slide-nav .navbar-toggle .icon-bar:nth-of-type(3) {
        top: 2px;
    }

    #slide-nav .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
        position: relative;
        transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    }

    #slide-nav .navbar-toggle.active .icon-bar:nth-of-type(1) {
        top: 6px;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }

    #slide-nav .navbar-toggle.active .icon-bar:nth-of-type(2) {
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    #slide-nav .navbar-toggle.active .icon-bar:nth-of-type(3) {
        top: -6px;
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
}


@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1032px)
{
    /* put toggle bars on the left :: not using button */
    #slide-nav .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    #slide-nav .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
        float: right;
    }
}


@media (min-width:1033px)
{
    #page
    {
        left: 0!important
    }


    nav.shrink .btn-middle
    {
        padding-top: 10px;
    }

    nav.shrink .link-middle
    {
        padding-top: 20px;
    }

    #slide-nav .bloc-no-visibility-md
    {
        visibility: hidden;
        display: none !important;
    }

    #slide-nav .navbar-toggle {
        display: none;
    }

    /*wrap the entire page content but not nav inside this div if not a fixed top, don't add any top padding */
    #page {
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 130px;
        left: 0;
    }

    #slide-nav #navbar-header-detail
    {
        visibility: hidden;
        display: none !important;
    }

    #slide-nav.navbar
    {
        height: auto;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #C0B0AA;
    }

    #slide-nav .btn-margin-right
    {
        margin-right: 10px;
    }

    #slide-nav .navbar-nav > li > a
    {
        padding-top: 4px;
        padding-bottom: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }

    #slide-nav .btn-middle .navbar-btn
    {
        padding: 6px 8px 26px 8px;
    }

    .link-middle
    {
        padding-top: 40px;
    }

    .btn-middle
    {
        padding-top: 30px;
    }

    #slide-nav .btn
    {
        height: 20px;
    }

    #slide-nav .avatar
    {
        margin-right: 5px;
    }

    #slide-nav.navbar.navbar-fixed-top.slide-active
    {
        position: fixed
    }

    #slide-nav .navbar-header
    {
        left: 0!important
    }

    #slide-nav ul.nav li:hover > ul.dropdown-menu
    {
        display: block;
    }

    #slide-nav .navbar-right
    {
        margin-right: 0;
    }

    #slide-nav .nabvar-cart-nb
    {
        position: absolute;
        top:-8px;
        right: 5px;
        width: 18px;
        height: 18px;
        background-color: #23527c;
        border-radius: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #FFF;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    #slide-nav .navbar-cart i
    {
        color: #E8412A;
    }

    #slide-nav .nav > li > .no-background:hover, #slide-nav .nav > li > .no-background:focus {
        background: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="slide-nav" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://thestartupexpert.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/sample-logo.png" width="350" height="83" alt=""></a>
        </div>



        <div id="slidemenu">
            <div class="navbar-right text-center">
                <div id="navbar-header-detail">
                    <img src="https://thestartupexpert.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/sample-logo.png" class="img-responsive img-circle avatar-navbar-xs">
                    <span class="navbar-cart"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket fa-2x"></i><span class="sr-only"> Panier</span><span class="nabvar-cart-nb">1</span></a></span>
                </div>

                <ul id="menuNavBar" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="bloc-no-visibility-md btn-margin-right btn-middle"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn">Un premier bouton</a></li>
                    <li class="bloc-no-visibility-md btn-middle"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn">Un deuxième bouton</a></li>

                    <li class="link-middle bloc-no-visibility-sm navbar-cart"><a href="#" class="no-background"><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i><span class="sr-only"> Panier</span><span class="nabvar-cart-nb">1</span></a></li>

                    <li id="menu-global" class="dropdown link-middle btn-margin-right">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><img src="http://www.brillianthospitality.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/default-avatar_0.png" height="23" width="23" class="img-circle avatar">Alain <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-2x picto-margin-right bloc-no-visibility-md" aria-hidden="true"></i> Mon profil</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-2x picto-margin-right bloc-no-visibility-md" aria-hidden="true"></i> Mon profil</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-2x picto-margin-right bloc-no-visibility-md" aria-hidden="true"></i> Mon profil</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-2x picto-margin-right bloc-no-visibility-md" aria-hidden="true"></i> Mon profil</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-2x picto-margin-right bloc-no-visibility-md" aria-hidden="true"></i> Mon profil</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-2x picto-margin-right bloc-no-visibility-md" aria-hidden="true"></i> Mon profil</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-question-circle fa-2x picto-margin-right bloc-no-visibility-md" aria-hidden="true"></i> Aide</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>


                    <li id="menu-aide" class="dropdown link-middle btn-margin-right">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Aide <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link test long title goes here</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="btn-margin-right btn-middle bloc-no-visibility-sm"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn">Un premier bouton</a></li>
                    <li class="btn-middle bloc-no-visibility-sm"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn">Un deuxième bouton</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>


<div id="page">
    <div id="page-content" class="container">
        <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a
            mostly barebones HTML a a a a a a a f.</p>

        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a
            mostly barebones HTML a a a a a a a f.</p>

        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a
            mostly barebones HTML a a a a a a a f.</p>

        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a
            mostly barebones HTML a a a a a a a f.</p>

        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a
            mostly barebones HTML a a a a a a a f.</p>

        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a
            mostly barebones HTML a a a a a a a f.</p>

        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a
            mostly barebones HTML a a a a a a a f.</p>

        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a
            mostly barebones HTML a a a a a a a f.</p>

        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a
            mostly barebones HTML a a a a a a a f.</p>

        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a
            mostly barebones HTML a a a a a a a f.</p>

        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a
            mostly barebones HTML a a a a a a a f.</p>

        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a
            mostly barebones HTML a a a a a a a f.</p>

        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a
            mostly barebones HTML a a a a a a a f.</p>

        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a
            mostly barebones HTML a a a a a a a f.</p>

        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a
            mostly barebones HTML a a a a a a a f.</p>

        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a
            mostly barebones HTML a a a a a a a f.</p>

        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a
            mostly barebones HTML a a a a a a a f.</p>

        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a
            mostly barebones HTML a a a a a a a f.</p>

        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a
            mostly barebones HTML a a a a a a a f.</p>

        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. All you get is this text and a
            mostly barebones HTML a a a a a a a f.</p>
    </div>
 
</div>
```